# Doing that wouldn't do you any harm vs Doing that wouldn't harm you

Tags: american-english

I got a question. Let's say two people are talking about riding the rollercoaster:

**Person1** says to person number two:

**Let's ride the rollercoaster, it's quite fun!**

Then, **person2** says:

**I'm afraid of rollercoasters**.

Then **person2** replies to **person1**:

Come on, it won't (**do you any**) harm you!

Do I have to have **(do)**  before harm for it to sound natural or can I just say "it won't **harm** you"?

Answer (score 4):

Normal usage would be: "Come on, it won't do you any harm!" (lose the final, repetitive 'you') but your alternative of "it won't harm you!" is also fine, though "it won't *hurt* you!" sounds more natural to me.

Comment: My father and I had practically the same conversation when I was seven years old. He insisted, dragging me on the rollercoaster, and I vomited profusely once it got really going, which did me some "harm", I daresay. It certainly harmed his trousers and jacket.